# Убрать вложенность массива php

Tags: php, массивы

Работая с VK api получаю нужные мне массивы в цикле for и вбиваю их в arr[] (чтобы вывести за цикл все значения полученных массивов)

Получается такое:

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [0] => 442907096 [1] => 157301381 ) 
[1] => Array ( [0] => 321333396 [1] => 434343381 ) 
)
```

А нужен такой:

Array ( [0] => 442907096 [1] => 157301381 [2] => 321333396 [3] => 434343381 )

Что посоветуете?

Comment: Ну например - слить через `$arr = array_merge($arr[0],$arr[1])` в один массив.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Вариант 1

```
<?php

$array = [
    0 => [0 => 442907096, 1 => 157301381],
    1 => [0 => 321333396, 1 => 434343381] 
];

$outArray = [];
foreach ($array as $item) {
    foreach ($item as $item2) {
        $outArray[] = $item2;
    }
}

print_r($outArray);
```

#### Вариант 2

```
<?php

$array = [
    0 => [0 => 442907096, 1 => 157301381],
    1 => [0 => 321333396, 1 => 434343381] 
];

$outArray = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $array);

print_r($outArray);
```

#### Результат обоих вариантов

```
Array
(
    [0] => 442907096
    [1] => 157301381
    [2] => 321333396
    [3] => 434343381
)
```